# Doing `F; class F{};` makes `F` both an undefined variable, and an already defined identifier. Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-console

Doing `F; class F{}` on the chrome console gives a reference error (`F is not defined`), but after that, doing `class F{}` again yields `Identifier 'F' has already been declared`, while `F;` yields a reference error (even `typeof F` gives a reference error!).

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

[image]

Comment: it's a bug in your code if you're doing that :p

Comment: It makes sense because of the “temporal dead zone” (the reason `(function () { return typeof X; class X {} })()` is a `ReferenceError` instead of `"undefined"`), but probably isn’t the ideal behaviour for a console.

Comment: Works fine for me. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3px.png

Comment: @BrendanLong You haven't done `F; class F{};` (same line!).

Comment: `F` `Enter`, then `class F{}` `Enter` should not log `Identifier 'F' has already been declared` `SyntaxError`. What are you trying to determine?

Comment: What is the purpose of the exercise?